# Class auto apply in ckeditor img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

for my CMS i use together CKEDITOR and Superslides .
Superslides transforms any images inside his tags in background slide if not uses class "prevent" in img.
So, i need that any images added with ckeditor contain class='prevent' automatically without selecting custom styles or similar on texteditor.
My client cannot write 'prevent' in class field for each image or selecting custom format/style.

I try this:

```
$('.ckeditor img').addClass("preserve");
```

or

```
$('.contentslide img').addClass("preserve");
```

Maybe , a solution could be a placeholder in class field , like this for dialog tab ' link ' but do not know how to apply for images.

ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
    {
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        // Check if the definition is from the dialog window you are interested in (the "Link" dialog window).
        if ( dialogName == 'link' )
        {
            // Get a reference to the "Link Info" tab.
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

            // Set the default value for the URL field.
            var urlField = infoTab.get( 'url' );
            urlField['default'] = 'www.example.com';
        }
    });
```

Solutions?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you got this sorted, but this worked for me

```
var cssField = infoTab .get('advCSSClasses');
    cssField['default'] = 'className';
```